# Finding Maximum value in an Array of Objects by ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have a series of data that contains some objects in an array(json file) and it will be shown by `fetch` request.There is a `renderMaxTotal()` function that must get me the max number of in `totalcom`of all data of json file but it shows me the max number of in `totalcom` in the current page and by going to another page the amount of `renderMaxTotal()` will be changed.

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [],
        library: null,
        perPage: 20,
        currentPage: 1,
        maxPage: null,
    };
}
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/json.bc', {
        method: 'get',
    })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(text => {
            let Maindata = JSON.parse(text.replace(/\'/g, '"'))
            this.setState(state => ({
                ...state,
                data: Maindata
            }), () => {
                this.reorganiseLibrary()
            })
        }).catch(error => console.error(error))
}
reorganiseLibrary = () => {
    const { perPage, data } = this.state;
    let library = data;
    library = _.chunk(library, perPage);
    this.setState({
        library,
        currentPage: 1,
        maxPage: library.length === 0 ? 1 : library.length
    })
}

// Previous Page
previousPage = event => {
    this.setState({
        currentPage: this.state.currentPage - 1
    })
}
// Next Page 
nextPage = event => {
    this.setState({
        currentPage: this.state.currentPage + 1
    })
}

// handle per page
handlePerPage = (evt) =>
    this.setState({
        perPage: evt.target.value
    }, () => this.reorganiseLibrary());

// handle render of library
renderLibrary = () => {
    const { library, currentPage } = this.state;
    if (!library || (library && library.length === 0)) {
        return <div className="nodata">No Result</div>
    }
    return library[currentPage - 1].sort((a, b) => a.total - b.total).map((item, i) => (
        <div className="item">
            <span>{this.renderTotalcom(item)}</span>
        </div>
    ))
}
// handle render of library
renderMaxTotal = () => {
    const { library, currentPage } = this.state;
    if (!library || (library && library.length === 0)) {
        return <div className="nodata">No Result</div>
    }
    return Math.max(...library[currentPage].map(item => item.totalCom))
}
render() {
    const { library, currentPage, perPage, maxPage } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <span className="max">{this.renderMaxTotal()}</span>
            {this.renderLibrary()}
            <ul id="page-numbers">
                <li className="nexprevPage">
                    {currentPage !== 1 && (
                        <button onClick={this.previousPage}><span className="fa-backward"></span></button>
                    )}
                </li>
                <li className="controlsPage active">{this.state.currentPage}</li>
                <li className="restControls">...</li>
                <li className="controlsPage">{this.state.maxPage}</li>
                <li className="nexprevPage">
                    {(currentPage < maxPage) && (<button onClick={this.nextPage}><span className="fa-forward"></span></button>
                    )}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
renderTotalcom(element) {
    console.log(typeof element.totalCom)
    return element.totalCom
  } 
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('Result'))
```

If I change `renderMaxTotal()` to this:
`Math.max(...library[0].map(item=>item.totalCom))`
it will show me the max of first page and by turning to another page it does not change.
If I change `renderMaxTotal()` to this:
`Math.max(...library.map(item=>item.totalCom))`
it will be `NaN`.
How can I have the max amount of `totalcom` in whole pages?

Comment: Please take the time to format your code so that it's easier for us to help you.

Comment: Sorry.Is it ok now?

Comment: Looks good! What is the shape of `this.state.data`? If it's working and then stops working on re-render, it's likely that the shape is getting changed somehow. Can you show what the json file looks like?

Comment: It is something like this:`[{'_id':'8856', 'totalCom': 12875000.0}, {'_id':'7865','totalCom': 13875000.0}, { '_id':'6633','totalCom': 9479000.0}.......................]` with some others fileds in every object of my array. Every thing is fine but I don not know how to find the maximum value of 'totalcom'  in whole pages not only current page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will get the max of each pages and compare it with the current Max.

```
// handle render of library
renderMaxTotal = () => {
  const { library } = this.state;
  if (!library || (library && library.length === 0)) {
      return <div className="nodata">No Result</div>
  }
  return library.reduce((acc,lib)=>{
      const libMax = Math.max(...lib.map(item => item.totalCom))
      return libMax > acc ? libMax : acc
  },0)
}
```

Comment: For minimum value I should do something like this:

Comment: `return library.reduce((acc,lib)=>{
      const libMin = Math.min(...lib.map(item => item.totalCom))
      return libMin < acc ? libMin : acc
  },0)`

Comment: Nah, your accumulator is defaultly set to 0, so the minimum will always be 0 (or a negative value).

You have to set your accumulator first value to undefined, and in the first step, if acc === undefined return libMin

Comment: yeah. It turns me 0.So what should I do?

Comment: `return library.reduce((acc,lib)=>{
      const libMin = Math.min(...lib.map(item => item.totalCom))
      return acc === undefined ? libMin : libMin < acc ? libMin : acc
  },undefined)`

Comment: Great!Thanks a lot.